# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'model'

Tags: python, python-3.x, anki

I am trying to solve the problem I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65307547/how-to-convert-a-csv-into-several-apkg-every-x-number-of-lines-with-genanki), i.e, creating multiple 1000 note .apkg from one .csv
How I explain there, "I have a script that receives a .csv file and creates an apkg (anki program format). What I want is to create a .apkg deck for every certain number of lines the user enters. For example, if I have a deck.csv file with 4200 lines, and I choose to divide it into 1000 note decks it should generate the files:

```
deck 1-1000.apkg
deck 1001-2000.apkg
deck 2001-3000.apkg
deck 3001-4000.apkg
deck 4001-4200.apkg
```

The code I have tried now is.

```
import csv
import random
import genanki

# Filename of the data file
data_filename = str(input("Enter input file name with extension: "))

# Filename of the Anki deck to generate
deck_filename = data_filename.split('.')[0] + ".apkg"

# Title of the deck as shown in Anki
anki_deck_title = data_filename.split('.')[0]

# Name of the card model
anki_model_name = "Modelname"

# Create the deck model

model_id = random.randrange(1 << 30, 1 << 31)

style = """
.card {
 font-family: arial;
 font-size: 24px;
 text-align: center;
 color: black;
 background-color: white;
"""

anki_model = genanki.Model(
    model_id,
    anki_model_name,
    fields=[{"name": "front"}, {"name": "back"}],
    templates=[
        {
            "name": "Card 1",
            "qfmt": '{{front}}',
            "afmt": '{{FrontSide}}<hr id="answer">{{back}}</p>',
        },
    ],
    css=style,
)

# The list of flashcards
anki_notes = []

with open(data_filename, "r", encoding="utf-8") as csv_file:

    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=";")

    for row in csv_reader:
        anki_note = genanki.Note(
            model=anki_model,
            fields=[row[0], row[1]]
        )
        anki_notes.append(anki_note)

for subdeck in range(int((round((len(anki_notes)/1000)+0,5)))):
  anki_deck = genanki.Deck(model_id, anki_deck_title+" "+str((subdeck-1)*1000+1)+"-"+str(subdeck*1000))
  anki_package = genanki.Package(anki_deck)

  # Add flashcards to the deck
  for anki_note in range(1000):
      anki_deck.add_note(anki_note)

  # Save the deck to a file
  anki_package.write_to_file(deck_filename)
  print("Created deck with {} flashcards".format(len(anki_deck.notes)))
```

But I get the error

```
Enter input file name with extension: CLDR.csv
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-a8b71afba302> in <module>()
     65 
     66   # Save the deck to a file
---> 67   anki_package.write_to_file(deck_filename)
     68   print("Created deck with {} flashcards".format(len(anki_deck.notes)))

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/genanki/deck.py in write_to_db(self, cursor, timestamp, id_gen)
     59     models = json.loads(models_json_str)
     60     for note in self.notes:
---> 61       self.add_model(note.model)
     62     models.update(
     63       {model.model_id: model.to_json(timestamp, self.deck_id) for model in self.models.values()})

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'model'
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Well, what data type does `write_to_file` require?  What did you send it?  Your post should print out at *least* that much information, and then trace those values back to the point of discrepancy.  Why is the input process part of your post?  Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.

Comment: Those are good tips! Excuse my ignorance, I'm a newbie at this. I'll edit the post as soon as I can, I'm not in my office right now. In the meantime I can direct you to a playable version on google collab here https://colab.research.google.com/drive/19AI6h-_H_AmgbnFCTQkJJvmN4WiJ3afQ?usp=sharing
I've also uploaded a sample file called test.csv so that you can experiment until the MRE comes up. Documentation on genanki can be found here https://github.com/kerrickstaley/genanki

Thank you very much for your help and patience. I come back soon.

Comment: error shows problem in file `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/genanki/deck.py` so you could open it and add `print()` and `print( type(...) )` to see values in variable - it should help you see which values are wrong in your data. It seems it gets integer instead of object with varaible `.model`. BTW: It is `"print debuging"` OR learn how to use real debuger.

Comment: are you sure for line `for anki_note in range(1000): anki_deck.add_note(anki_note)` ? It adds numbers `0... 1000` to `anki_deck` and probalby you want to add cards. maybe you need `add_note(anki_notes[anki_note])` instead of `add_note(anki_note)`. maybe problem is because you have two variables with similar names - `anki_notes` and `anki_note`. Maybe you should use `for anki_note in anki_notes` instead of `for anki_note in range(1000):`. And maybe use variable which more different - ie `for note in anki_notes` instead of `for anki_note in anki_notes`

Comment: Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable; we need your question to be self-contained, in keeping with the purpose of this site.

Comment: As for the "good tips", those are basic debugging points, which we expect you to carry out before posting here.  Keep in mind the stated charter of Stack Overflow. Our main criterion is whether other people are likely to run into this issue, whether the answer already exists elsewhere on line, and whether the posting is clear enough that they will have an easy time to find an answer. Solving it for the original poster is sort of a side effect.

Comment: See this [lovely debugging site](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will guess but I think all your problem is beause you use two variables with similar name `anki_notes` and `anki_note` or beacuse you use the same name `anki_note` it two places and you could use it in wrong way.

First you use `anki_note` when you create notes

```
 anki_note = Note(...)
```

and in `anki_note` you have object which has field `.model`

But later you use `anki_note` for integers.

```
 for anki_note in range(1000):
```

and in next line you add `anki_note` to `anki_deck` like it would be `Note`

```
 #for anki_note in range(1000):
     anki_deck.add_note(anki_note)
```

So finally you add integers to `anki_deck` instead of `Notes` and later error shows in line `self.add_model(note.model)` that it gets integer instead of object  with field `.model`

So probably you should use `anki_notes[anki_note]` in `add_note`

```
for anki_note in range(1000):
    anki_deck.add_note( anki_notes[anki_note] )
```

Or you should use `anki_notes` instead of `range(1000)`

```
for anki_note in anki_notes:
    anki_deck.add_note( anki_note )
```

---

**BTW:**

I didn't test it but maybe instead of complex

```
for subdeck in range(int((round((len(anki_notes)/1000)+0,5)))):

str((subdeck-1)*1000+1) + "-" + str(subdeck*1000)
```

you need simpler

```
for subdeck in range(0, len(anki_notes), 1000):

str(subdeck+1) + "-" + str(subdeck+1000)
```